# jQuery UI, sortables and Cookie plugin with multiple lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI sortable plugin with the cookie plugin to set and get the list of two sortable lists.

I found this piece of code to set and get a cookie: http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/#comment-6441

It works as I want to for one list, but not two (I've made the changes listed in the comments but fail somewhere).

My guess is that I have to specify the first and the second list for the setSelector and not use a class for the list. I tried "var setSelector = "#first, #second"; but that that doesn't do it.

Ideas?

Thanks

$(function() {

```
// set the list selector
var setSelector = ".sortable";
// set the cookie name
var setCookieName = "listOrder";
// set the cookie expiry time (days):
var setCookieExpiry = 7;

// function that writes the list order to a cookie
function getOrder() {
    // save custom order to cookie
    $.cookie(setCookieName, $(setSelector).sortable("toArray"), { expires: setCookieExpiry, path: "/" });
}

// function that restores the list order from a cookie
function restoreOrder() {
    var list = $(setSelector);
    if (list == null) return

    // fetch the cookie value (saved order)
    var cookie = $.cookie(setCookieName);
    if (!cookie) return;

    // make array from saved order
    var IDs = cookie.split(",");

    // fetch current order
    var items = list.sortable("toArray");

    // make array from current order
    var rebuild = new Array();
    for ( var v=0, len=items.length; v<len; v++ ){
        rebuild[items[v]] = items[v];
    }

    for (var i = 0, n = IDs.length; i < n; i++) {

        // item id from saved order
        var itemID = IDs[i];

        if (itemID in rebuild) {

            // select item id from current order
            var item = rebuild[itemID];

            // select the item according to current order
            var child = $("ul" + setSelector + ".ui-sortable").children("#" + item);

            // select the item according to the saved order
            var savedOrd = $("ul" + setSelector + ".ui-sortable").children("#" + itemID);

            // remove all the items
            child.remove();

            // add the items in turn according to saved order
            // we need to filter here since the "ui-sortable"
            // class is applied to all ul elements and we
            // only want the very first!  You can modify this
            // to support multiple lists - not tested!
            $("ul" + setSelector + ".ui-sortable").filter(":first").append(savedOrd);

        }
    }
}

// code executed when the document loads
$(function() {
    // here, we allow the user to sort the items
    $(setSelector).sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        items: 'li',
        //axis: "y",
        opacity: 0.6,
        //revert: true,
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 40,
        placeholder: 'highlight',
        update: function() { getOrder(); }
    });

    // here, we reload the saved order
    restoreOrder();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

_http://code.google.com/p/cookies/

_http://noteskeeper.ru/article/save-state-jquery-ui-sortable/

```
   root = $("#sidebar");
     $('> *', root).each(function (index) {
      this.id = 'block-' + index;
     });
     root.sortable({
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true,
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
     });

     // function that writes the list order to a cookie
     root.bind( "sortupdate", function (event, ui) {
      // save custom order to cookie
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
            $.cookies.set('sortable', order);
        });

     // here, we reload the saved order
     // fetch the cookie value (saved order)
     var c = $.cookies.get('sortable');
     if (c) {
      // function that restores the list order from a cookie
      $.each(c.split('&'), function () {
       var id = this.replace('[]=', '-');
       $('#' + id).appendTo(root);
      });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the code

`var setSelector = ".sortable";`

to

`var setSelector = "#sortable";`