# jQuery UI Sortable and JS Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, jquery-ui-sortable

**The Statement**
Okay, so I've been trying to get [jQuery UI's Sortable Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/sortable) to work on my website. You can check out their API [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable) if you're not familiar with the plugin. After a few days of debugging (have had many problems with the plugin) it's finally working good. Then I spent a couple of days working on a non-practical way of storing the order as cookies with PHP which was having some problems---and I'd rather not do it with PHP anyway.

Enter [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) I'm sure you're all familiar with. I've used it before and am even using it to store the toggled states of said sortable sections, but I'm certainly not a pro with it (in fact, I'm new to Javascript/jQuery altogether really).

Anyway, I've seen several questions on StackOverflow, and other places, discussing the topic and introducing solutions from various people. However, all of these solutions seem to be 1-4 years old, and not working for me. It could simply be that I'm doing something wrong in implementing their code--- it's certainly not in impossibility, me being pretty inexperienced and all.

That being said, I would appreciate it if you would look at my demo / code and tell me what's wrong, or simply help me re-write it entirely to get it working.

**The Code**

```
function restoreOrder() {
    var cookie = $.cookie('cookie_name');
    if (!cookie) return;
    var SavedID = cookie.split('|');
    for ( var u=0, ul=SavedID.length; u < ul; u++ ){ SavedID[u] = SavedID[u].split(',');}
    for (var Scolumn=0, n = SavedID.length; Scolumn < n; Scolumn++) {
        for (var Sitem=0, m = SavedID[Scolumn].length; Sitem < m; Sitem++) {
            $("#sortablemain").eq(Scolumn).append($("#sortablemain").children("#" + SavedID[Scolumn][Sitem]));
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    handle: "h3",
    cursor: "move",
    axis: "y",
    placeholder: "marker",
    opacity: 0.3,
    scrollSpeed: 50,
    containment: '#sortable',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    revert: 200,
    helper: 'clone',
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    });
});

$(function() {
    $( "#sortablemain" ).sortable({
    handle: "h2",
    cursor: "move",
    axis: "y",
    placeholder: "marker",
    opacity: 0.3,
    scrollSpeed: 50,
    containment: '#sortablemain',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    revert: 200,
    helper: 'clone',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) {
          var cooked = [];
          $( "#sortablemain" ).each(function(index, domEle){ cooked[index]=    $(domEle).sortable('toArray');});
          $.cookie('cookie_name', 'x'+cooked.join('|'), { expires: 7, path: '/'});
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    restoreOrder();
});
```

*[Above "solution" (not working) obtained from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370417/jquery-ui-sortable-and-cookie)]*

**The Sorting Demo** *[without cookies]**[working]***:
http://jsfiddle.net/mQGdS/

**The Sorting Demo** *[with cookies]**[not working -- sorting still works, cookies don't]***:
http://jsfiddle.net/48tJM/2

**Another failed cookie demo attempt (different cookie method)**:
http://jsfiddle.net/mQGdS/3 (obtained from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746800/jquery-ui-sortables-and-cookie-plugin-with-multiple-lists?rq=1)).

Still no luck. :(

**In Closing** *[clarification]*
The above jsFiddle (with cookies) is only attempting to create a cookie for #sortablemain. In reality, I need to create 2 separate cookies, storing the order of each of the two lists, #sortable and #sortablemain separately. As shown in the jsFiddle demos, I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2

Much (really <3) appreciated,
Dustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, remember boys are girls... You need to include external js, such as cookie.jquery.js...

All of the cookie methods I tried apparently work. I just wasted many hours because I simply forgot to include cookie.jquery.js

Nice work.

The final working example: http://jsfiddle.net/48tJM/5/

```
function restoreOrderSidebar() {
    var cookie = $.cookie('cookie_sidebar');
    if (!cookie) return;
    var SavedID = cookie.split('|');
    for ( var u=0, ul=SavedID.length; u < ul; u++ ){ SavedID[u] = SavedID[u].split(',');}
    for (var Scolumn=0, n = SavedID.length; Scolumn < n; Scolumn++) {
        for (var Sitem=0, m = SavedID[Scolumn].length; Sitem < m; Sitem++) {
            $("#sortable").eq(Scolumn).append($("#sortable").children("#" + SavedID[Scolumn][Sitem]));
        }
    }
}

function restoreOrderMain() {
    var cookie = $.cookie('cookie_main');
    if (!cookie) return;
    var SavedID = cookie.split('|');
    for ( var u=0, ul=SavedID.length; u < ul; u++ ){ SavedID[u] = SavedID[u].split(',');}
    for (var Scolumn=0, n = SavedID.length; Scolumn < n; Scolumn++) {
        for (var Sitem=0, m = SavedID[Scolumn].length; Sitem < m; Sitem++) {
            $("#sortablemain").eq(Scolumn).append($("#sortablemain").children("#" + SavedID[Scolumn][Sitem]));
        }
    }
}

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    handle: "h3",
    cursor: "move",
    axis: "y",
    placeholder: "marker",
    opacity: 0.3,
    scrollSpeed: 50,
    containment: '#sortable',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    revert: 200,
    helper: 'clone',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) {
          var cooked = [];
          $( "#sortable" ).each(function(index, domEle){ cooked[index]=    $(domEle).sortable('toArray');});
          $.cookie('cookie_sidebar', 'x'+cooked.join('|'), { expires: 31, path: '/'});
      }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $( "#sortablemain" ).sortable({
    handle: "h2",
    cursor: "move",
    axis: "y",
    placeholder: "marker",
    opacity: 0.3,
    scrollSpeed: 50,
    containment: '#sortablemain',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    revert: 200,
    helper: 'clone',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    update: function(event, ui) {
          var cooked = [];
          $( "#sortablemain" ).each(function(index, domEle){ cooked[index]=    $(domEle).sortable('toArray');});
          $.cookie('cookie_main', 'x'+cooked.join('|'), { expires: 31, path: '/'});
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    restoreOrderMain();
    restoreOrderSidebar();
});
```